# Can't resolve 'rxjs-compat/observable/combineLatest'

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have upgraded my angular project to

```
"rxjs": "^6.3.3"
```

I have used `combineLatest` operator, but after upgrading, I am facing issues and compilation is failed

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/observable/combineLatest.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs-compat/observable/combineLatest' in 'D:\MyProject\node_modules\rxjs\observable'
```

I am importing like

```
import { map, distinctUntilChanged, filter, combineLatest } from "rxjs/operators";
```

even I have updated the syntax

```
_col$.pipe(combineLatest(this.meta$.asObservable()))
```

Do I need to install `rxjs-compat`?

But I [read this](https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/)

> rxjs-compat provides a temporary compatibility layer between the APIs
>   of v5 and v6. Essentially, rxjs-compat provisions your codebase with
>   functionality from v5 that it relies on, allowing you to gradually
>   upgrade your codebase to v6. To complete the upgrade process and
>   remove the rxjs-compat dependency from your project,

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably somewhere in your app using the old style of "patch" operators. For example like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest'
```

If you want to keep using this style then you need to install also `rxjs-compat` package.

Anyway consider migrating to pipable operators:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: Little confused, I tried `import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest'` but this is showing error as well, Do i need to install the `rxjs-compat` to use `combineLatest` or there is an alternative for this? I have updated the question as well..

Comment: Yes, `import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest'` won't work without `rxjs-compat` since RxJS 6.

Comment: But this is not recommended, right? Any alternative for this?

Comment: There are two links in my answer regarding this

Comment: `Eventually, you will want to drop the compatibility layer to complete the update to RxJS v6. Doing so will significantly decrease the size of your apps.` -> they have deprecated this, then is there any alternative for this?

Comment: It's right there in my answer... *"Anyway consider migrating to pipable operators"* with a link to https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: You should indeed move to pipeable operators, and dont fallback to rxjs-compat, if possible. Also, you might also see these errors because some of your dependencies still rely on the old version of rxjs.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest updates you can import `combineLatest` like this:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
```